# How to decouple validation process from saving results to DB by WCF service or other technique?

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, performance

I build some validation service.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var service = new ValidationManager();
    service.Start();

    System.Console.ReadLine();

    service.Stop();
}
```

`ValidationManager` using `ThreadPool` to execute `Validate` method that receives input to check. To simplify the problem - `Validate` method just do some regex checking. After thread finishes validation it should save the result to DB. Without DB saving the service does 60,000 validations within 10 seconds. With DB saving it does about 5,000 validaitons. To improve the performance I use some `BulkManager` that receives the validation results from threads and saves the results to DB by bulks. `BulkManager` uses itself `ThreadPool` to save the bulks to DB. This did improved. Now `ValidationManager` does about 11,000 validations.

I thought that if I could decouple `BulkManager` from `ValidationManager` to different **process** it would improve more. So, I created console WCF service with `netNamedPipeBinding` in the same solution.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISqlBulkWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SaveLog(string email, string summary);
    [OperationContract]
    void SaveFinalResult(string email, byte resultType, string summary);    
}

public class SqlBulkWCFService: ISqlBulkWCFService
{
    public void SaveLog(string email, string summary)
    {
    }
    public void SaveFinalResult(string email, byte resultType, string summary)
    {
    }
}
```

I added webservice reference to `ValidationManager` project and instead to do `sqlManager.SaveLog(...)` I do `sqlBulkWCFServiceClient.SaveLog(...)`. But, now `ValidationManager` does **ONLY 100 validations**.

I though it will be faster, because one process does validation and the other saving to DB. And I thought the communication with WCF service will be fast because the client and server in the same machine.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you've created a addition service with is doing the saving. I wouldn't recommend doing this as you create a lot of overhead that doesn't sound reasonable to me. Which im explains the decreasing performance.

Is it really ok that you de-couple the validation from DB saving? if you do the validation and then add it to the buffer for a bulk-operation you might loose data in case e.g. the service crashes. If this is not ok, I'd keep the chain calls -> validation -> DB save and just play around with the trottle settings. With higher concurrency of the WCF service the throughput should go up, if the DB has the capacity for it.

If the bulk solution is fine for you, you can utilize the BlockingCollection from the TPL.
So with service startup you start a saving-thread that uses the GetConsumingEnumerable to save what comes in, and all the WCF calls are doing the validation and at the end add it result to the collection.
To save unnecessary DB calls you can use some thread sleeps to wait that some results accumulate in the collection.

hth,
Martin